# YouCompleteMe plugin for VIM - how to support autocompletion for other libraries' methods ? (e.g. openmpi)

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

YCM autocompletes and highlights errors on C++ standard library. However, if I download another library such as OpenMPI and write code that imports `<mpi.h>` I can compile it with mpicc but YCM tells me that `<mpi.h>` file was not found and all it's provided functions seem to by marked invalid by YCM. Is there a way to fix this ? What changes should I make to `ycm_extra_conf_py` file to support other downloaded libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while searching for an answer myself. The only solution I have found so far is to manually edit compile_commands.json and add the required mpi include dir, eg run

```
mpicc -showme
```

and append the relevant

```
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi
```

options to the conf file. I haven't seen the contents of ycm_extra_conf_py but I guess there is something similar to do. I hope this helps.